# Restricting result of scipy minimization (SLSQP)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I would like to minimize an objective function which calls an simulation software in every step and returns a scalar. Is there any way to restrict the result of the objective function? For example I would like to get the values of the variables which bring the result as closest to 1 as possible.

I tried to simply subtract 1 from the result of the objective function but that didn't help. I also played around with coinstraints but if I understand it corretly they are only for the input variables. Another way could be to create an log which stores the values of all variables after every iteration (which I'm doing already). In the end it should be possible to search for the iteration which had a result closest to 1 and return it's variable configuration. The problem is that the minimization probably runs way too long and creates useless results. Is there any better way?

```
def objective(data):
     """
     Optimization Function
     :param data: list containing the current guess (list of float values)
     :return: each iteration returns a scalar which should be minimized
     """

     # do simulation and calculate scalar

     return result - 1.0   # doesn't work since result is becoming negative
```

```
def optimize(self):
     """
     daemon which triggers input, reads output and optimizes results
     :return: optimized results
     """

     # initialize log, initial guess etc.

     sol = minimize(self.objective, x0, method='SLSQP', options={'eps': 1e-3, 'ftol': 1e-9}, bounds=boundList)
```

The goal is to find a solution which can be adapted to any target value. The user should be able to enter a value and the minimization will return the best variable configuration for this target value.

Comment: Would `(result - 1.0) ** 2` do the trick? Then results cannot become negative and the minimization should result in `result = 1`(or something close by).

Comment: That would be a really simple solution and it looks promising. I will try it tomorrow, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, one way of achieving this is to use

```
return (result - 1.0) ** 2
```

in `objective`. Then the results cannot become negative and the optimization will try to find `result` in such a way that it is close to your target value (e.g. `1.0` in your case).

Illustration, using first your current set-up:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def objective(x, target_value):

    # replace this by your actual calculations
    result = x - 9.0

    return result - target_value


# add some bounds for all the parameters you have
bnds = [(-100, 100)]

# target_value is passed in args; feel free to add more
res = minimize(objective, (1), args=(1.0,), bounds=bnds)

if res.success:
    # that's the optimal x
    print(f"optimal x: {res.x[0]}")
else:
    print("Sorry, the optimization was not successful. Try with another initial"
          " guess or optimization method")
```

As we chose `-100` as the lower bound for `x` and ask to minimize the objective, the optimal `x` is `-100` (will be printed if you run the code from above). If we now replace the line

```
return result - target_value
```

by

```
return (result - target_value) ** 2
```

and leave the rest unchanged, the optimal `x` is `10` as expected.

Please note that I pass your target value as additional argument so that your function is slightly more flexible.

Comment: @Sley: Very glad to hear! :)